# C++ - memory leak caused by using placement new over *this pointer?

Tags: c++

As we know, placement new just constructs an object without allocating any memory. Also all members in the class `Resource` are objects instead of pointers, although `std::string` internally holds a dynamic array which will be freed when the `std::string` object is being destroyed. And `*this` points to the memory allocated on the stack, which means the destructor will be always called. So I think what placement new does here is just overwriting the original object. Here is a simple example. The memory usage keeps going up while I run this example (on VS 2019).

```
class Resource
{
public:
    Resource() {};
    Resource(const std::string& s) : str(s)
    {
        new(this)Resource();
    }
    

private:
    std::string str;

}; 


int main()
{
    while (true)
        Resource resource("hello");
}
```

Comment: Call the destructor before placement new: `this->~Resource();`. Using placement new here basically just memcopies over the old string which means the old string's content is lost.

Comment: Because of *short string optimization* may need a string longer than `"hello"` to trip the bug on some platforms.

Comment: Most, actually. A 64 bit platform has room for 21 characters plus terminator before it has to dynamically allocate memory, if memory serves on the implementation detail, and 9 (plus terminator) on a 32 bit platform. I'm looking askance, though, at placement-constructing `this` **after** assigning `str(s)`...

Comment: @Mestkon makes sense

Comment: There should be no reason to use placement `new` on `this`; you can simply use a delegating constructor to the default constructor, which will have the same effect since you are immediately blowing away the value given to `str`

Comment: @Mestkon Are you sure you can call destructor for an object that has not been yet fully constructed?

Comment: @DanielLangr Calling the destructor for an object whose lifetime has not yet begun is indeed UB. I suspect the legality of such a construct is the same as using placement new on `this` in a constructor though as the accepted answer explains.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The standard (latest draft) says:

> [basic.life]
>
> A program may end the lifetime of any object by reusing the storage which the object occupies ... if there is no explicit call to the destructor or if a delete-expression is not used to release the storage, **the destructor is not implicitly called and any program that depends on the side effects produced by the destructor has undefined behavior**.

So, since the constructor reuses the storage of `*this` for a dynamic object **without calling the destructor** of the original object, that destructor is never called. That destructor is where the string member would have been destroyed and its memory deallocated.

---

Conclusion: Don't Placement-new over `*this`.